# Use Scalable CSS Spritesheet

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to use a CSS Spritesheet for my icons. Every icon image has a size of 48x48px. However, I want to be able to display icons with arbitrary dimension.

Right now, I'm using, to display a 24x24 icon, I use:

`<div style="width:24px;height:24px;display:inline-block">
    <div class="tab-achievement sprite" style="transform:scale(0.5);transform-origin:0 0"></div>
</div>`

Is there a shorter way to do so? For example, by using `::before` and `::after`.

Ultimately, I'd like something like:

`<div class="img24x24 tab-achievement sprite"></div>`

Demo goal: Display the proper icon with Hello World.

```css
 .sprite {display:inline-block; overflow:hidden; background-repeat: no-repeat;background-image:url(http://puu.sh/nWh8y.png);}

.tab-achievement {width:48px; height:48px; background-position: -48px -48px}
```

```html
<div>
<div style="width:24px;height:24px;display:inline-block">
 <div class="tab-achievement sprite" style="transform:scale(0.5);transform-origin:0 0"></div> 
</div> <span>Hello World.</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Updated to address cropping issue*

Here is a solution using pseudo element

```css
.sprite:before {
  content: ' ';
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: url(http://puu.sh/nWh8y.png) no-repeat;
  width:48px;
  height:48px;
  transform-origin:0 0;
}
.sprite:after {
  content: attr(data-text);
}
.tab-achievement:before {
  background-position: -48px -48px;
}
.tab-locker:before {
  background-position: -48px 0;
}
.img24x24:before {
  transform: scale(0.5);
}
.img36x36:before {
  transform: scale(0.75);
}
```

```html
<div class="img24x24 tab-achievement sprite">
  <span>Hello World.</span>
</div>

<div class="img36x36 tab-achievement sprite">
  <span>Hello World.</span>
</div>

<div class="tab-achievement sprite">
  <span>Hello World.</span>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="img36x36 tab-locker sprite" data-text="Hello World - pseudo only">
</div>
```

Comment: I'll make a clear demo. What you posted doesn't work.

Comment: @RainingChain Updated my answer, better?

Comment: What browser are you using? Because on Chrome, Firefox and IE, your snippet doesn't work. The image is cropped rather than scaled.

Comment: @RainingChain I see that now ... will have a look soon

Comment: @RainingChain Thanks for asking instead of down voting, my bad, didn't noticed that, updated and working.